# How can I get msysgit on windows to invoke node.js scripts in hooks?

Tags: node.js, git, githooks, msysgit

I would like to use node.js scripts as my git hook scripts. Currently I'm experimenting on my Windows machine with Bonobo Git HTTP service which is attached to msysgit Git-1.9.0-preview20140217 portable installation. It works fine, tested with copuple pulls and pushes.

I have nodejs up and running but my git `update` script just fails without any clear reason. It definitely works - it started to always reject pushes as soon as I added it into the hooks folder on the server but there are no any clues in SourceTree output log.

Here is my update script:

```
#!C:/nodejs/node.exe

console.log('Hello world!');
console.log('Hello world 2!');
```

I tried back slashes, I tried double forward slashes, I tried quoting the path - no results.

Server response is as follows:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to http://myurl.git

POST git-receive-pack (4686 bytes)

remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master[K

To http://myurl.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'http://myurl.git'


Completed with errors, see above.
```

P.S. I don't know where `[K` comes from, my gusess is that it's corrupted newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using similar approach to the one I found someone was using for Python.

I created a C# console app as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace GitNodeRunner
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Path to script file not specified");

                return -1;
            }

            string argString = string.Join(" ", args);
            Console.WriteLine("Node.js arguments received: {0}", argString);

            string nodePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NODE_HOME",
                EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); // without "Machine" Git's Bash loses it

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nodePath))
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("NODE_HOME global envirnoment variable not found");

                return -1;
            }

            nodePath = Path.Combine(nodePath, "node.exe");

            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Arguments = argString,
                FileName = nodePath,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = start;

            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.ErrorDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.Start();

            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            return process.ExitCode;
        }

        static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = e.Data;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
        }

        static void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = e.Data;
            Console.Error.WriteLine(s);
        }
     }
}
```

I compiled it as git-nodejs.exe, put into Git's `bin` folder, ensured that I have `NODE_HOME` environment variable defined, and now I can use node.js scripts. As an example, I provide my node.js update hook which rejects pushes with malformed comment messages:

```js
#!/bin/git-nodejs

// bin/git-nodejs is our custom C# programmed node launcher

// the following code is ported from http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

// we have some offset from standard Git args here:
// 0 is path to node
// 1 is path to this script
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
refname = process.argv[2],
oldrev  = process.argv[3],
newrev  = process.argv[4],
regexMatch = /^REF #\d* /; // in my case I require strict start with "REF #number "

console.log("Enforcing policies in branch " + refname + " for commits between revisions " + oldrev + " and " + newrev);

// we have a special case - if this is a new branch, oldrev..newrev will cause git to throw an error, 
// that's why we check for empty branch commit ID
var revListCmd = (oldrev === "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000") ? 
                    "git rev-list " + newrev + " --not --branches=*" : 
                    "git rev-list " + oldrev + ".." + newrev;

exec(revListCmd,
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error !== null) {
          console.error("Exec error: " + error);
          exitError();
        }

        var missedRevs = stdout.split("\n");
        missedRevs.forEach(function(rev){
            // there is a redundant empty entry at the end after split()
            if (rev.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            console.log("Verifying policy for revision " + rev);

            //  | sed '1,/^$/d' does not quite work as expected on Windows 
            // - it returns all commit details instead of comment
            // thus we complete the processing from JavaScript
            exec("git cat-file commit " + rev,
              function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                    if (error !== null) {
                      console.error("Exec error: " + error);
                      exitError();
                    }

                    // we skip the blank line (two sequential newlines) and take everything that follows
                    // not sure if this is the best solution but "it works on my machine"
                    var commitMessage = stdout.split("\n\n")[1];    
                    // notice: if commit message missing, git will report it as "no message"

                    if (commitMessage.match(regexMatch) === null) {
                        console.error("Commit message '" + commitMessage + "' does not match the required pattern " + regexMatch);  
                        exitError();
                    }

            });
        }); 
    });


//////////////////////////
// some helpers

function exitError()
{
    // hack for bug https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584
    // delay exit until stdout on Windows has had some time to flush
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.error("Exiting with error status 1");
      process.exit(1);
    }, 1000);
}
```